# Sharing baked ami in Spinnaker with Prod account after Staging deployment

Tags: spinnaker, spinnaker-halyard

I am trying to evaluate Jenkins+Spinnaker as our CI/CD platform and i would like to say it worked perfectly for us till Staging environment. We are using AWS and AMIs for our flow.

Now, our requirement is that we want to share AMI with Prod account, which is a completely different account from UAT and Staging, only when it passes QA in Staging env as we want to keep only those image in our prod account which have passed quality gates. I tried searching some suggestion for same but didn't found any. Though there were some blogs on sharing AMI with different regions which baking step using aws-multi-ebs.json, which is not our requirement.

Is there any inbuilt process in Spinnaker itself for the same or i need to use some outside job, like integrating with Jenkins, for copying the AMI to Prod env ?

Answer (score 0):

Spinnaker will do this by default via allow launch (the AMI remains owned by the baking account but when you deploy to the prod account launch permission is granted to that account)

Comment: Thanks @cfieber. I wasn't aware of this feature. Will it be possible for you to add some details here or point me to some good article on this? I am still confused with, if i have a baked image ready in Staging env and i want to create a new pipeline for Prod deployment after some Manual Judgement, then i can directly start with adding the deployment step in new pipeline (selecting Prod account from configuration) and it will automatically copy image to prod account or i need to first add some step before starting deployment in prod so that image is available in prod account first.